# How to create reduce duplicated code for Primefaces/JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm working on a JSF project and have a lots duplicated code like the following:

As you can see the two cell editor are pretty much the same, only the value is different. But I still can't find a way to avoid the duplication.

```
<p:column headerText="DF" >
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{payLeg.df}">
                <f:convertNumber pattern="###,##0.00" />
            </h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputNumber value="#{payLeg.df}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Forward Forward Rate" >
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{payLeg.fwdfwd}">
                <f:convertNumber pattern="###,##0.00" />
            </h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputNumber value="#{payLeg.fwdfwd}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

I tried to create a column composite like

```
    <html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
<h:body>
    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="headerText"/>
        <composite:attribute name="value"/>
    </composite:interface>
    <composite:implementation>
        <p:column headerText="#{cc.attrs.headerText}">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
                        <f:convertNumber pattern="###,##0.00" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputNumber value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
    </composite:implementation>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And use it like

```
<components:editableNumberColumn headerText="Year Fraction" value="#{payLeg.yearFrac}" />
            </p:dataTable>
```

But I guess as I created it as a components. So dataTable doesn't recognize it as a column. So the column didn't show up.

So is there any similar method I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want use a composite component you should exclude `p:column`. With next implementation it's should work:

```
<composite:implementation>
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
                <f:convertNumber pattern="###,##0.00" />
            </h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputNumber value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</composite:implementation>
```

And usage of this component looks like:

```
<p:column>
    <components:editableNumberColumn headerText="Year Fraction" value="#{payLeg.yearFrac}" />
</p:column>
```

Second way it's create template with name *MyNumberColumn.xhtml* (for example) like this:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <p:column headerText="#{headerText}">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{value}">
                    <f:convertNumber pattern="###,##0.00" />
                </h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputNumber value="#{value}" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

</ui:composition>
```

And incude it into datatable:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{values..}" var="v" ...>
    <ui:include src="MyNumberColumn.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="headerText" value="Header for first column"/>
        <ui:param name="value" value="#{men.name}"/>
    </ui:include>

    <ui:include src="MyNumberColumn.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="headerText" value="Header for second column"/>
        <ui:param name="value" value="#{men.name}"/>
    </ui:include>
</p:dataTable>
```